# Django - conditional mandatory fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django form to capture Username/Password and a Sign-In button. Clearly I need Username/Password to be mandatory.

I also want to have a Register button on the same form, where the Username/Password fields can't be mandatory.

How do I validate the form in a way that is dependent on the button that has been pressed.

Normally Validation is done on the forms `clean` method, but the `clean` method has no access to the selected button - just the entered fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered the answer - it is not very well documented in the official documents - so here it is :

Within the `clean` method on the form as well as having access to the cleaned data, the program also has access to `self.data` which is the uncleaned data - i.e with the hidden fields, and buttons available (the cleaned data only has the input fields available but not the `input type="submit"` buttons- so my html form has this (approximately) :

```
<form method="post" action="" >                    
    <table>                
        <tr>
           <th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="id_username" maxlength="30" /></td></tr>
        <tr>
           <th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='submit' name='register' value='Register'/></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign In'/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and in my Django form - the clean method is :

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    register = self.data.get('register')
    signin = self.data.get('submit')

    if signin:
        if not (cleaned_data.get('username') and cleaned_data.get('password')):
             self.add_error('username', 'Must provide your scouts.org.uk Username to sign in')
             self.add_error('password', 'Must provide your scouts.org.uk password to sign in')

        return cleaned_data
    elif register:
        return cleaned_data
```

Note the use of self.data to access the form data for the buttons